# How to hyphenate only words within a list?

Tags: hyphenation

I would like to prevent TeX from doing automatic hyphenation except when a word that could be hyphenated is found in a list of given hyphenation words like the following:

```latex
\hyphenation{
    be-rufen
    be-unruhigten
    Er-zieher
    geschicht-lichen
    Künstler-hand
    meister-haft
    Meister-haft
    Mittel-meer
    Vergangen-heit
    Vor-geschichte
    Vor-stellung
    Vor-stellungen
    wissen-schaftliche
    zu-getragen
}
```

`\hyphenpenalty=10000` prevents hyphenation completely what I don't want. Not loading `babel` will not prevent hyphenation but instead make the hyphenation worse.
I would like to achieve a manual solution (LuaTeX only would also be ok).

Comment: Try this: `\usepackage[hyphenmap=off]{babel}`

Comment: @hair-splitter seems to work, thanks! Do you want to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hyphenmap=off]{babel}

\hyphenation{
    be-rufen
    be-unruhigten
    Er-zieher
    geschicht-lichen
    Künstler-hand
    meister-haft
    Meister-haft
    Mittel-meer
    Vergangen-heit
    Vor-geschichte
    Vor-stellung
    Vor-stellungen
    wissen-schaftliche
    zu-getragen
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

berufen
beunruhigten
Erzieher
geschichtlichen
Künstlerhand
meisterhaft
Meisterhaft
Mittelmeer
Vergangenheit
Vorgeschichte
Vorstellung
Vorstellungen
wissenschaftliche
zugetragen

\kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyphenmap=off` is irrelevant here. There is no hyphenation because `\usepackage{babel}` sets the language to `nil`, which has no patterns.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the `babel` manual, to suppress hyphenation you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=+]{ngerman}
```

Then add:

```
\babelhyphenation{
    be-rufen
    be-unruhigten
    Er-zieher
    geschicht-lichen
    Künstler-hand
    meister-haft
    Meister-haft
    Mittel-meer
    Vergangen-heit
    Vor-geschichte
    Vor-stellung
    Vor-stellungen
    wissen-schaftliche
    zu-getragen
}
```

You have still access to the language features (translations, date, shorthands, etc.), but a new empty set of hyphenation patterns is created, and since it’s empty, there are no hyphens, except, of course, those in `\babelhyphenation`. With `luatex` you can even add patterns with `\babelpatterns` (which is not possible with `pdftex` or `xetex`).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to keep the main language. It would be my next to do step, to create own split-patterns, but only those that are definetly splitting compound words like `z-g`, `z-k`, `k-g`, `g-k` and so on, I don't want to split syllables. I found the LuaTeX-only part, but it looks rather complex to me to implement those simple patterns.

Comment: For future readers: if used together with `microtype` put the `\usepackage` for `microtype` *between* `\usepackage[language]{babel}` and `\babelprovide...`